# Passive voice: see somebody ___ (send) back into society

Tags: passive-voice, infinitive-vs-gerund, past-participles

Which one should I fill in the blank

[being sent/ to be sent/ sent]:

> Without access to books in prison, my world view would still be shaped by violence. It’s not who I want to see (  ) back into society.

Comment: To what does "it" refer in the second sentence? Is that possibly a typographical error for **I'm**?

Comment: I think it refers to “what I would’ve been like had I not read all those books”.

Comment: Use the past tense of send.

Comment: [Which one should I fill in the blank **with**?]

Answer (score 0):

Being sent is most passive and "sent" alone is best English.

Comment: I think "being" here is progressive, unrelated to the passive. "We were being sent there" and "We were sent there" are equally passive.

Comment: @nschneid I agree. "We were being sent there" is a worse sentence, though.